# Python3 add element to every list of lists

Tags: python, list, append, addition, extend

I'm iterating through excell sheet row by row and read cell values to list. For every row of data I need to add to the end two more things extracted from sheet name, which are being stored in list DI_DJ = [el1, el2]

My code look like this:

```
data_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row])
data_rows.extend(DI_DJ)
```

and it gives as output list which has structure like:

> [[value, of, cells, in, row], el1, el2]

what I'm trying to get is:

> [[value, of, cells, in, row, el1, el2]]

I've looked for answer, tried

> data_rows += DI_DJ

but I always ended up with same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just add the list comprehension results with the list DI_DJ?

```
data_rows.append([cell.value for cell in row] + DI_DJ)
```

Comment: Thank you, works like charm :)
Sorry to even bother, newbie here.

Comment: No worries at all! Thanks for posting all of the details/examples in your question.